# Vuex Store accessing state with 'this'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, store

I'm currently learning Vuex and reading [this](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations) part of the official Vue documentation. I was wondering if there's a particular reason why we would access `state` with argument instead of just using `this`? I tested if things will work with `this` which it did.

**Vue Example**

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 1
  },
  mutations: {
    increment (state) {
      state.count++
    }
  }
})
```

**My Example**

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 1
  },
  mutations: {
    increment () {
      this.count++;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you post the full working code or a codesandbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Vuex store instance is not an ordinary object that has its own `this`, it could be seen as black box that offers some input/output for that it passes the state as parameter and then inside its logic (pattern) updates the state according to your mutation, for `this` available here:

```
 mutations: {
    increment () {
      this.count++;
    }
  }
```

it refers to the global `window` object.

According to @Spinx comments `this` refers to vuex instance in version 3 and later and i find that what @Matt said is a good note :

> IMO this is a great example of why you should use the explicit parameter since you don't know how your function is bound __Matt

Comment: @Sphinx yes it refers to window please check [this](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/LYNOaZx)

Comment: the context may be `window` object or `Vuex instance` based on the implementation. check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u5wv3gy8/)

Comment: so what's the difference between my code and yours ? and what are that contexts?

Comment: version issue, I forked your project and changed the Vuex version from `2.0` to `3.0`, then the context in your project becomes `Vuex instance`; check [this codepen](https://codepen.io/cj2018work/pen/yLOPwPL?editors=1111); anyway, the developer should not rely on the default context, should always follow the user guide to use the parameter to access the state/context.

Comment: IMO this is a great example of why you should use the explicit parameter since you don't know how your function is bound

Comment: agree. your statement answered the question.

Comment: thank you for your remarks i updated my answer based on what you provided